# Appium test doesn't even start on AWS DeviceFarm

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, appium, aws-device-farm

I have run somel iOS Appium tests (Java TestNG) on iOS devices for my app.

Some tests don't even install the app, on six or seven out of 22 devices. All with the exact same error about not creating a session:

```
Trying to execute simple Appium Driver
Failed to invoke configuration method scenarios.ScreenshotsAppiumTest.setUp:
It is impossible to create a new session because 
'createSession' which takes HttpClient, 
InputStream and long was not found or it is not accessible
```

The test works and passes on all my devices and almost all other devices on AWS Device Farm.
In those devices where it fails, it does nothing. It doesn't install the app.

I have no idea how to debug this test or why they are not running. Google doesn't help.

I am positive the test works, since it works on other devices.

I'd like to know how to debug or try to solve this error. What are the steps to debug Appium not installing the app on AWS Device Farm?
What can I do? Is there any command to execute to get more logs? Anything?
I have asked this same question on AWS Forum without any luck.... 
Thanks.

The error I have in the logs this one:

```
RUNNING: Suite: "test" containing "1" Tests (config: /private/tmp/scratchudZ8pO.scratch/testng_xml93e7D5/screenshotsTest.xml)
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ Keeping method ScreenshotsAppiumTest.setUp()pri:0, instance:scenarios.ScreenshotsAppiumTest@4e04a765 for class http://TestClass name=class scenarios.ScreenshotsAppiumTest
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ Invoking @BeforeClass ScreenshotsAppiumTest.setUp()pri:0, instance:scenarios.ScreenshotsAppiumTest@4e04a765
INVOKING CONFIGURATION: "test" - @BeforeClass scenarios.ScreenshotsAppiumTest.setUp()
Trying to execute simple Appium Driver
Failed to invoke configuration method scenarios.ScreenshotsAppiumTest.setUp:It is impossible to create a new session because 'createSession' which takes HttpClient, InputStream and long was not found or it is not accessible
Build info: version: '3.12.0', revision: '7c6e0b3', time: '2018-05-08T14:04:26.12Z'
System info: host: 'prod-osx-device-host-master-v18.local', ip: 'fe80:0:0:0:82:486b:ed14:4cef%en0', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.13.2', java.version: '1.8.0_141'
Driver info: driver.version: AppiumDriver
FAILED CONFIGURATION: "test" - @BeforeClass scenarios.ScreenshotsAppiumTest.setUp() finished in 0 ms
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: It is impossible to create a new session because 'createSession' which takes HttpClient, InputStream and long was not found or it is not accessible
Build info: version: '3.12.0', revision: '7c6e0b3', time: '2018-05-08T14:04:26.12Z'
System info: host: 'prod-osx-device-host-master-v18.local', ip: 'fe80:0:0:0:82:486b:ed14:4cef%en0', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.13.2', java.version: '1.8.0_141'
Driver info: driver.version: AppiumDriver
at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor$1.createSession(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:182)
at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.createSession(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:196)
at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.execute(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:218)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:543)
at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.execute(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:42)
at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.execute(AppiumDriver.java:1)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:207)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:130)
at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.<init>(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:38)
at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.<init>(AppiumDriver.java:84)
at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.<init>(AppiumDriver.java:94)
at scenarios.TestSetup.prepareDriver(TestSetup.java:117)
at scenarios.ScreenshotsAppiumTest.setUp(ScreenshotsAppiumTest.java:44)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:84)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:564)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:213)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:138)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeBeforeClassMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:175)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:107)
at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)
at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:348)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:343)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:305)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:254)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1224)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1149)
at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1057)
at org.testng.TestNG.privateMain(TestNG.java:1364)
at org.testng.TestNG.main(TestNG.java:1333)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor$1.createSession(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:172)
... 35 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: unexpected end of stream on Connection{127.0.0.1:4723, proxy=DIRECT hostAddress=/127.0.0.1:4723 cipherSuite=none protocol=http/1.1}
at okhttp3.internal.http1.Http1Codec.readResponseHeaders(Http1Codec.java:205)
at okhttp3.internal.http.CallServerInterceptor.intercept(CallServerInterceptor.java:88)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:45)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:93)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:125)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:200)
at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:77)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.OkHttpClient.execute(OkHttpClient.java:105)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:101)
... 40 more
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: \n not found: limit=0 content=…
at okio.RealBufferedSource.readUtf8LineStrict(RealBufferedSource.java:227)
at okhttp3.internal.http1.Http1Codec.readHeaderLine(Http1Codec.java:212)
at okhttp3.internal.http1.Http1Codec.readResponseHeaders(Http1Codec.java:189)
... 57 more
INVOKING: "test" - scenarios.ScreenshotsAppiumTest.screenshotsTest()
SKIPPED: "test" - scenarios.ScreenshotsAppiumTest.screenshotsTest() finished in 0 ms
browses the page the title
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ Keeping method ScreenshotsAppiumTest.tearDown()pri:0, instance:scenarios.ScreenshotsAppiumTest@4e04a765 for class http://TestClass name=class scenarios.ScreenshotsAppiumTest
SKIPPED CONFIGURATION: "test" - @AfterClass scenarios.ScreenshotsAppiumTest.tearDown() finished in 0 ms
```

Comment: Could you post the appium server output too? That should have there underlying error.

Comment: Found a GitHub issue with same error. https://github.com/appium/java-client/issues/926

I haven't reproduced this but it looks like this is due might be caused by the java client for appium.  

Could you add the pom file too? There might be something that the local tests has but the device host doesn't.

Comment: Which java version and java appium client version are you using? Also, could you put the devices the tests work on and the ones that fail so I can reproduce the issue?

Comment: There error is coming from this method in the java client. https://github.com/appium/java-client/blob/master/src/main/java/io/appium/java_client/remote/AppiumCommandExecutor.java#L177-L201 looking into it more..

Comment: It looks like a few commits were just merged with regards to the okhttp client that the appium java client uses. https://github.com/appium/java-client/pull/928 This may have been related as the error is with regards to the session being created. Would you be able to update your java client and let me know if the issue still happens?

Comment: @jmp Thanks, jmp, I am using version 6.0.0 of the Java Appium Driver client. That's the last one as far as I am concernced. I am repeating the test now and will update logs, devices, and appium log. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update. I have found devices with this issue. It looks like it happens on

```
Apple iPad 2 iOS version 9
Apple iPad Air 2 iOS version 9
Apple iPad Mini 1st Gen iOS version 9
Apple iPad Mini 3 
Apple iPad Pro 9.7" iOS version 10
Apple iPhone 5s iOS version 9
Apple iPhone 7 Plus iOS version 10
```

On versions 9 of iOS. I am not worring too much about it because it looks like a version issue. I accept my own answer until future research and checking other versions.

For future reference here's the log of one device:

```
[TestNG] RUNNING: Suite: "test" containing "1" Tests (config: /tmp/scratchK72Ot0.scratch/testng_xmlK427pl/second_login_is_much_faster.xml)
[Invoker 310656974] Keeping method LoginDurationAppiumTest.setUp()[pri:0, instance:scenarios.LoginDurationAppiumTest@64616ca2] for class [TestClass name=class scenarios.LoginDurationAppiumTest]
[Invoker 310656974] Invoking @BeforeClass LoginDurationAppiumTest.setUp()[pri:0, instance:scenarios.LoginDurationAppiumTest@64616ca2]
[TestNG] INVOKING CONFIGURATION: "test" - @BeforeClass scenarios.LoginDurationAppiumTest.setUp()
Trying to execute simple Appium Driver
Failed to invoke configuration method scenarios.LoginDurationAppiumTest.setUp:It is impossible to create a new session because 'createSession' which takes HttpClient, InputStream and long was not found or it is not accessible
Build info: version: '3.12.0', revision: '7c6e0b3', time: '2018-05-08T14:04:26.12Z'
System info: host: 'ip-172-31-13-65', ip: '172.31.13.65', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.13.0-139-generic', java.version: '1.8.0_151'
Driver info: driver.version: AppiumDriver
[TestNG] FAILED CONFIGURATION: "test" - @BeforeClass scenarios.LoginDurationAppiumTest.setUp() finished in 0 ms
[TestNG] org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: It is impossible to create a new session because 'createSession' which takes HttpClient, InputStream and long was not found or it is not accessible
[TestNG] Build info: version: '3.12.0', revision: '7c6e0b3', time: '2018-05-08T14:04:26.12Z'
[TestNG] System info: host: 'ip-172-31-13-65', ip: '172.31.13.65', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.13.0-139-generic', java.version: '1.8.0_151'
[TestNG] Driver info: driver.version: AppiumDriver
[TestNG]    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor$1.createSession(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:182)
[TestNG]    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.createSession(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:196)
[TestNG]    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.execute(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:218)
[TestNG]    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:543)
[TestNG]    at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.execute(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:42)
[TestNG]    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.execute(AppiumDriver.java:1)
[TestNG]    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:207)
[TestNG]    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:130)
[TestNG]    at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.<init>(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:38)
[TestNG]    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.<init>(AppiumDriver.java:84)
[TestNG]    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.<init>(AppiumDriver.java:94)
[TestNG]    at scenarios.TestSetup.prepareDriver(TestSetup.java:119)
[TestNG]    at scenarios.LoginDurationAppiumTest.setUp(LoginDurationAppiumTest.java:46)
[TestNG]    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[TestNG]    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
[TestNG]    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[TestNG]    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
[TestNG]    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:84)
[TestNG]    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:564)
[TestNG]    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:213)
[TestNG]    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:138)
[TestNG]    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeBeforeClassMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:175)
[TestNG]    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:107)
[TestNG]    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)
[TestNG]    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)
[TestNG]    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:348)
[TestNG]    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:343)
[TestNG]    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:305)
[TestNG]    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:254)
[TestNG]    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
[TestNG]    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
[TestNG]    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1224)
[TestNG]    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1149)
[TestNG]    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1057)
[TestNG]    at org.testng.TestNG.privateMain(TestNG.java:1364)
[TestNG]    at org.testng.TestNG.main(TestNG.java:1333)
[TestNG] Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
[TestNG]    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[TestNG]    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
[TestNG]    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[TestNG]    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
[TestNG]    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor$1.createSession(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:172)
[TestNG]    ... 35 more
[TestNG] Caused by: java.io.IOException: unexpected end of stream on Connection{127.0.0.1:4723, proxy=DIRECT hostAddress=/127.0.0.1:4723 cipherSuite=none protocol=http/1.1}
[TestNG]    at okhttp3.internal.http1.Http1Codec.readResponseHeaders(Http1Codec.java:205)
[TestNG]    at okhttp3.internal.http.CallServerInterceptor.intercept(CallServerInterceptor.java:88)
[TestNG]    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
[TestNG]    at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:45)
[TestNG]    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
[TestNG]    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
[TestNG]    at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:93)
[TestNG]    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
[TestNG]    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
[TestNG]    at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93)
[TestNG]    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
[TestNG]    at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:125)
[TestNG]    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
[TestNG]    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
[TestNG]    at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:200)
[TestNG]    at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:77)
[TestNG]    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.OkHttpClient.execute(OkHttpClient.java:105)
[TestNG]    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:101)
[TestNG]    ... 40 more
[TestNG] Caused by: java.io.EOFException: \n not found: limit=0 content=…
[TestNG]    at okio.RealBufferedSource.readUtf8LineStrict(RealBufferedSource.java:227)
[TestNG]    at okhttp3.internal.http1.Http1Codec.readHeaderLine(Http1Codec.java:212)
[TestNG]    at okhttp3.internal.http1.Http1Codec.readResponseHeaders(Http1Codec.java:189)
[TestNG]    ... 57 more
[TestNG] INVOKING: "test" - scenarios.LoginDurationAppiumTest.second_login_is_much_faster()
[TestNG] SKIPPED: "test" - scenarios.LoginDurationAppiumTest.second_login_is_much_faster() finished in 10 ms
[TestNG]          Checks if the second time the app logs in is much faster
[Invoker 310656974] Keeping method LoginDurationAppiumTest.tearDown()[pri:0, instance:scenarios.LoginDurationAppiumTest@64616ca2] for class [TestClass name=class scenarios.LoginDurationAppiumTest]
[TestNG] SKIPPED CONFIGURATION: "test" - @AfterClass scenarios.LoginDurationAppiumTest.tearDown() finished in 0 ms
===== Invoked methods
  LoginDurationAppiumTest.setUp()[pri:0, instance:scenarios.LoginDurationAppiumTest@64616ca2] 1684106402
    LoginDurationAppiumTest.second_login_is_much_faster()[pri:0, instance:scenarios.LoginDurationAppiumTest@64616ca2] 1684106402
=====
```