# Error : impossible to create a new session because 'createSession' which takes HttpClient, InputStream and long was not found

Tags: android, automation, appium, hybrid-mobile-app

I am trying to automate an android hybrid app but getting following errors:

> 1) Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: It is    impossible to create a new session because 'createSession' which takes HttpClient, InputStream and long was not found or it is not accessible
>
> 2) Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>
> 3) Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: No such context found.
>
> 4) NoSuchContextError: No such context found.

Following is the code I’m trying to execute

```
package Demo;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Set;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.CapabilityType;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.MobileElement;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
public class NewTest {

private static AndroidDriver<MobileElement> driver;
public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException, InterruptedException {

DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "android");
capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "ZY223ZMPG6");
capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "7.0");
capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
capabilities.setCapability("autoGrantPermissions","true");
capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", "com.equationswork.enis");
capabilities.setCapability("appActivity", "com.equationswork.enis.MainActivity");
capabilities.setCapability("--session-override","true");
capabilities.setCapability("autoWebview","true");
capabilities.setCapability("chromedriverExecutable","C:\\Users\\Anjani \\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\appium\\node_modules\\appium-chromedriver\\chromedriver\\win\\chromedriver.exe");
AppiumDriver<MobileElement> driver = new AndroidDriver<MobileElement>(new  URL("http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
        //driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(80, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        //System.out.println(driver.getPageSource());
Set<String> contextNames = driver.getContextHandles();
for (String contextName : contextNames) {
 System.out.println(contextNames); //prints out something like   NATIVE_APP \n WEBVIEW_1
        }
driver.context((String) contextNames.toArray()[1]);
driver.context("WEBVIEW_1");
driver.findElement(By.id("btnGuest")).click();
//driver.quit(); 
   }
}

Following are the errors thrown:
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: It is impossible to create a new session because 'createSession' which takes HttpClient, InputStream and long was not found or it is not accessible
Build info: version: '3.12.0', revision: '7c6e0b3', time: '2018-05-08T14:04:26.12Z'
System info: host: 'DESKTOP-LAHP4RL', ip: '10.0.0.65', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_171'
Driver info: driver.version: AndroidDriver
    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor$1.createSession(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:182)
    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.createSession(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:196)
    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.execute(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:218)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:543)
    at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.execute(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:42)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.execute(AppiumDriver.java:1)
    at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.execute(AndroidDriver.java:1)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:207)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:130)
    at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.<init>(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:38)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.<init>(AppiumDriver.java:84)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.<init>(AppiumDriver.java:94)
    at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.<init>(AndroidDriver.java:88)
    at Demo.NewTest.main(NewTest.java:31)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor$1.createSession(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:172)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: No such context found.
Build info: version: '3.12.0', revision: '7c6e0b3', time: '2018-05-08T14:04:26.12Z'
System info: host: 'DESKTOP-LAHP4RL', ip: '10.0.0.65', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_171'
Driver info: driver.version: AndroidDriver
remote stacktrace: NoSuchContextError: No such context found.
    at AndroidDriver.callee$0$0$ (C:\Users\Anjani\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-android-driver\lib\commands\context.js:49:11)
    at tryCatch (C:\Users\Anjani\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules\babel-runtime\regenerator\runtime.js:67:40)
    at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.invoke [as _invoke] (C:\Users\Anjani\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules\babel-runtime\regenerator\runtime.js:315:22)
    at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.prototype.(anonymous function) [as next] (C:\Users\Anjani\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules\babel-runtime\regenerator\runtime.js:100:21)
    at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.invoke (C:\Users\Anjani\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules\babel-runtime\regenerator\runtime.js:136:37)
    at <anonymous>
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.W3CHandshakeResponse.lambda$new$0(W3CHandshakeResponse.java:57)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.W3CHandshakeResponse.lambda$getResponseFunction$2(W3CHandshakeResponse.java:104)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.lambda$createSession$0(ProtocolHandshake.java:123)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.tryAdvance(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp.evaluateSequential(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.findFirst(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:126)
    ... 18 more

Following is the selenium server log

[Appium] Welcome to Appium v1.8.0
[Appium] Appium REST http interface listener started on 0.0.0.0:4723
[HTTP] --> POST /wd/hub/session
[HTTP] {"desiredCapabilities":{"appActivity":"com.equationswork.enis.MainActivity","appPackage":"com.equationswork.enis","chromedriverExecutable":"C:\\Users\\Anjani\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\appium\\node_modules\\appium-chromedriver\\chromedriver\\win\\chromedriver.exe","platformVersion":"7.0","autoGrantPermissions":"true","browserName":"android","--session-override":"true","autoWebview":"true","platformName":"Android","deviceName":"ZY223ZMPG6"},"capabilities":{"desiredCapabilities":{"appActivity":"com.equationswork.enis.MainActivity","appPackage":"com.equationswork.enis","chromedriverExecutable":"C:\\Users\\Anjani\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\appium\\node_modules\\appium-chromedriver\\chromedriver\\win\\chromedriver.exe","platformVersion":"7.0","autoGrantPermissions":"true","browserName":"android","--session-override":"true","autoWebview":"true","platformName":"Android","deviceName":"ZY223ZMPG6"},"firstMatch":[{"--session-override":"true","appium:appActivity":"com.equati
[debug] [MJSONWP] Calling AppiumDriver.createSession() with args: [{"appActivity":"com.equationswork.enis.MainActivity","appPackage":"com.equationswork.enis","chromedriverExecutable":"C:\\Users\\Anjani\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\appium\\node_modules\\appium-chromedriver\\chromedriver\\win\\chromedriver.exe","platformVersion":"7.0","autoGrantPermissions":"true","browserName":"android","--session-override":"true","autoWebview":"true","platformName":"Android","deviceName":"ZY223ZMPG6"},null,{"desiredCapabilities":{"appActivity":"com.equationswork.enis.MainActivity","appPackage":"com.equationswork.enis","chromedriverExecutable":"C:\\Users\\Anjani\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\appium\\node_modules\\appium-chromedriver\\chromedriver\\win\\chromedriver.exe","platformVersion":"7.0","autoGrantPermissions":"true","browserName":"android","--session-override":"true","autoWebview":"true","platformName":"Android","deviceName":"ZY223ZMPG6"},"firstMatch":[{"--session-override":"true","appium:appActivity":"com.equationswork.enis.MainActivity","appium:appPackage":"com.e...
[debug] [BaseDriver] Event 'newSessionRequested' logged at 1528700143344 (12:25:43 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time))
[BaseDriver] The capabilities ["--session-override"] are not standard capabilities and should have an extension prefix
[BaseDriver] Boolean capability passed in as string. Functionality may be compromised.
[Appium] Consider setting 'automationName' capability to 'uiautomator2' on Android >= 6, since UIAutomator framework is not maintained anymore by the OS vendor.
[Appium] Creating new AndroidDriver (v2.4.1) session
[Appium] Capabilities:
[Appium]   --session-override: true
[Appium]   browserName: android
[Appium]   platformName: android
[Appium]   appActivity: com.equationswork.enis.MainActivity
[Appium]   appPackage: com.equationswork.enis
[Appium]   autoGrantPermissions: true
[Appium]   autoWebview: true
[Appium]   chromedriverExecutable: C:\Users\Anjani\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-chromedriver\chromedriver\win\chromedriver.exe
[Appium]   deviceName: ZY223ZMPG6
[Appium]   platformVersion: 7.0
[debug] [BaseDriver] W3C capabilities {"alwaysMatch":{"appium:--s... and MJSONWP desired capabilities [object Object] were provided
[debug] [BaseDriver] Creating session with W3C capabilities: {"alwaysMatch":{"appium:--s...
[BaseDriver] Boolean capability passed in as string. Functionality may be compromised.
[BaseDriver] Boolean capability passed in as string. Functionality may be compromised.
[BaseDriver] Capability 'autoWebview' changed from string to boolean. This may cause unexpected behavior
[BaseDriver] Capability 'autoGrantPermissions' changed from string to boolean. This may cause unexpected behavior
[BaseDriver] The following capabilities were provided, but are not recognized by appium: --session-override.
[BaseDriver] Session created with session id: e5ce581e-243f-4a72-bc16-f2d84070f32b
[debug] [AndroidDriver] Getting Java version
[AndroidDriver] Java version is: 1.8.0_171
[ADB] Checking whether adb is present
[ADB] Found 1 'build-tools' folders under 'C:\Users\Anjani\AppData\Local\Android\sdk' (newest first):
[ADB]     C:/Users/Anjani/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/build-tools/23.0.3
[ADB] Using adb.exe from C:\Users\Anjani\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe
[AndroidDriver] Retrieving device list
[debug] [ADB] Trying to find a connected android device
[debug] [ADB] Getting connected devices...
[debug] [ADB] 1 device(s) connected
[AndroidDriver] Looking for a device with Android '7.0'
[debug] [ADB] Setting device id to ZY223ZMPG6
[ADB] Getting device platform version
[debug] [ADB] Getting connected devices...
[debug] [ADB] 1 device(s) connected
[debug] [ADB] Running 'C:\Users\Anjani\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s ZY223ZMPG6 shell getprop ro.build.version.release'
[debug] [ADB] Current device property 'ro.build.version.release': 7.0
[AndroidDriver] Using device: ZY223ZMPG6
[ADB] Checking whether adb is present
[ADB] Using adb.exe from C:\Users\Anjani\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe
[debug] [ADB] Setting device id to ZY223ZMPG6
[AndroidDriver] App file was not listed, instead we're going to run com.equationswork.enis directly on the device
[debug] [AndroidDriver] Checking whether package is present on the device
[debug] [ADB] Getting connected devices...
[debug] [ADB] 1 device(s) connected
[debug] [ADB] Running 'C:\Users\Anjani\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s ZY223ZMPG6 shell pm list packages com.equationswork.enis'
[AndroidDriver] Starting Android session
[debug] [ADB] Running 'C:\Users\Anjani\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s ZY223ZMPG6 wait-for-device'
[debug] [ADB] Getting connected devices...
[debug] [ADB] 1 device(s) connected
[debug] [ADB] Running 'C:\Users\Anjani\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s ZY223ZMPG6 shell echo ping'
[debug] [AndroidDriver] Pushing settings apk to device...
[debug] [ADB] Getting install status for io.appium.settings
[debug] [ADB] Getting connected devices...
[debug] [ADB] 1 device(s) connected
[debug] [ADB] Running 'C:\Users\Anjani\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s ZY223ZMPG6 shell pm list packages io.appium.settings'
[debug] [ADB] App is installed
[debug] [ADB] Getting package info for 'io.appium.settings'
[debug] [ADB] Getting connected devices...
[debug] [ADB] 1 device(s) connected
[debug] [ADB] Running 'C:\Users\Anjani\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s ZY223ZMPG6 shell dumpsys package io.appium.settings'
[ADB] Checking whether aapt is present
[ADB] Using aapt.exe from C:\Users\Anjani\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\23.0.3\aapt.exe
[debug] [ADB] The installed 'io.appium.settings' package does not require upgrade ('2.3.0' >= '2.3.0')
[debug] [ADB] Getting connected devices...
[debug] [ADB] 1 device(s) connected
[debug] [ADB] Running 'C:\Users\Anjani\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s ZY223ZMPG6 shell ps'
[debug] [ADB] Getting connected devices...
[debug] [ADB] 1 device(s) connected
[debug] [ADB] Running 'C:\Users\Anjani\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s ZY223ZMPG6 shell getprop ro.build.version.sdk'
[debug] [ADB] Current device property 'ro.build.version.sdk': 24
[debug] [ADB] Device API level: 24
[debug] [ADB] Getting connected devices...
[debug] [ADB] 1 device(s) connected
[debug] [ADB] Running 'C:\Users\Anjani\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s ZY223ZMPG6 shell am start -W -n io.appium.settings/.Settings -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER -f 0x10200000'[debug] [ADB] Device API level: 24
[debug] [ADB] Getting connected devices...
[debug] [ADB] 1 device(s) connected
[debug] [ADB] Running 'C:\Users\Anjani\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s ZY223ZMPG6 shell appops set io.appium.settings android\:mock_location allow'
[AndroidDriver] setDeviceLanguageCountry requires language or country.
[AndroidDriver] Got language: 'null' and country: 'null'
[debug] [Logcat] Starting logcat capture
[debug] [AndroidDriver] Pushing unlock helper app to device...
[debug] [ADB] Getting install status for io.appium.unlock
[debug] [ADB] Getting connected devices...
[debug] [ADB] 1 device(s) connected
[debug] [ADB] Running 'C:\Users\Anjani\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s ZY223ZMPG6 shell pm list packages io.appium.unlock'
[debug] [ADB] App is installed
[debug] [ADB] Getting package info for 'io.appium.unlock'
[debug] [ADB] Getting connected devices...
[debug] [ADB] 1 device(s) connected
[debug] [ADB] Running 'C:\Users\Anjani\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s ZY223ZMPG6 shell dumpsys package io.appium.unlock'
[ADB] Checking whether aapt is present
[ADB] Using aapt.exe from C:\Users\Anjani\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\23.0.3\aapt.exe
[debug] [ADB] The installed 'io.appium.unlock' package does not require upgrade ('2.0.0' >= '2.0.0')
[ADB] Getting device platform version
[debug] [ADB] Getting connected devices...
[debug] [ADB] 1 device(s) connected
[debug] [ADB] Running 'C:\Users\Anjani\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s ZY223ZMPG6 shell getprop ro.build.version.release'
[debug] [ADB] Current device property 'ro.build.version.release': 7.0
[debug] [ADB] Getting connected devices...
[debug] [ADB] 1 device(s) connected
[debug] [ADB] Running 'C:\Users\Anjani\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s ZY223ZMPG6 shell wm size'
[debug] [ADB] Getting connected devices...
[debug] [ADB] 1 device(s) connected
[debug] [ADB] Running 'C:\Users\Anjani\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s ZY223ZMPG6 shell getprop ro.product.model'
[debug] [ADB] Current device property 'ro.product.model': Moto G (5) Plus
[debug] [ADB] Getting connected devices...
[debug] [ADB] 1 device(s) connected
[debug] [ADB] Running 'C:\Users\Anjani\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s ZY223ZMPG6 shell getprop ro.product.manufacturer'
[debug] [ADB] Current device property 'ro.product.manufacturer': motorola
[AndroidDriver] No app sent in, not parsing package/activity
[debug] [AndroidDriver] No app capability. Assuming it is already on the device
[debug] [ADB] Getting install status for com.equationswork.enis
[debug] [ADB] Getting connected devices...
[debug] [ADB] 1 device(s) connected
[debug] [ADB] Running 'C:\Users\Anjani\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s ZY223ZMPG6 shell pm list packages com.equationswork.enis'
[debug] [ADB] App is installed
[debug] [ADB] Getting connected devices...
[debug] [ADB] 1 device(s) connected
[debug] [ADB] Running 'C:\Users\Anjani\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s ZY223ZMPG6 shell am force-stop com.equationswork.enis'
[debug] [ADB] Getting connected devices...
[debug] [ADB] 1 device(s) connected
[debug] [ADB] Running 'C:\Users\Anjani\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s ZY223ZMPG6 shell pm clear com.equationswork.enis'
[debug] [ADB] Device API level: 24
[debug] [ADB] Getting connected devices...
[debug] [ADB] 1 device(s) connected
[debug] [ADB] Running 'C:\Users\Anjani\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s ZY223ZMPG6 shell dumpsys package com.equationswork.enis'
[debug] [AndroidDriver] Performed fast reset on the installed 'com.equationswork.enis' application (stop and clear)
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] Watching for bootstrap disconnect
[debug] [ADB] Forwarding system: 4724 to device: 4724
[debug] [ADB] Running 'C:\Users\Anjani\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s ZY223ZMPG6 forward tcp\:4724 tcp\:4724'
[debug] [UiAutomator] Starting UiAutomator
[debug] [UiAutomator] Moving to state 'starting'
[debug] [UiAutomator] Parsing uiautomator jar
[debug] [UiAutomator] Found jar name: 'AppiumBootstrap.jar'
[debug] [ADB] Running 'C:\Users\Anjani\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s ZY223ZMPG6 push C\:\\Users\\Anjani\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\appium\\node_modules\\appium-android-bootstrap\\bootstrap\\bin\\AppiumBootstrap.jar /data/local/tmp/'
[debug] [ADB] Attempting to kill all uiautomator processes
[debug] [ADB] Getting all processes with uiautomator
[debug] [ADB] Getting connected devices...
[debug] [ADB] 1 device(s) connected
[debug] [ADB] Running 'C:\Users\Anjani\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s ZY223ZMPG6 shell ps'
[ADB] No uiautomator process found to kill, continuing...
[debug] [UiAutomator] Starting UIAutomator
[debug] [ADB] Creating ADB subprocess with args: ["-P",5037,"-s","ZY223ZMPG6","shell","uiautomator","runtest","AppiumBootstrap.jar","-c","io.appium.android.bootstrap.Bootstrap","-e","pkg","com.equationswork.enis","-e","disableAndroidWatchers",false,"-e","acceptSslCerts",false]
[debug] [UiAutomator] Moving to state 'online'
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Loading json...
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Registered crash watchers.
[AndroidBootstrap] Android bootstrap socket is now connected
[debug] [ADB] Getting connected devices...
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Client connected
[debug] [ADB] 1 device(s) connected
[debug] [ADB] Running 'C:\Users\Anjani\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s ZY223ZMPG6 shell dumpsys window'
[AndroidDriver] Screen already unlocked, doing nothing
[debug] [ADB] Device API level: 24
[debug] [ADB] Getting connected devices...
[debug] [ADB] 1 device(s) connected
[debug] [ADB] Running 'C:\Users\Anjani\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s ZY223ZMPG6 shell am start -W -n com.equationswork.enis/com.equationswork.enis.MainActivity -S -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER -f 0x10200000'
[AndroidDriver] Setting auto webview to context 'WEBVIEW_com.equationswork.enis' with timeout 2000ms
[debug] [AndroidDriver] Getting a list of available webviews
[debug] [ADB] Getting connected devices...
[debug] [ADB] 1 device(s) connected
[debug] [ADB] Running 'C:\Users\Anjani\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s ZY223ZMPG6 shell cat /proc/net/unix'
[debug] [AndroidDriver] Found webviews: ["WEBVIEW_chrome"]
[debug] [AndroidDriver] Available contexts: ["NATIVE_APP","WEBVIEW_chrome"]
[debug] [AndroidDriver] Getting a list of available webviews
[debug] [ADB] Getting connected devices...
[debug] [ADB] 1 device(s) connected
[debug] [ADB] Running 'C:\Users\Anjani\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s ZY223ZMPG6 shell cat /proc/net/unix'
[debug] [AndroidDriver] Found webviews: ["WEBVIEW_chrome"]
[debug] [AndroidDriver] Available contexts: ["NATIVE_APP","WEBVIEW_chrome"]
[debug] [AndroidDriver] Getting a list of available webviews
[debug] [ADB] Getting connected devices...
[debug] [ADB] 1 device(s) connected
[debug] [ADB] Running 'C:\Users\Anjani\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s ZY223ZMPG6 shell cat /proc/net/unix'
[debug] [AndroidDriver] Found webviews: ["WEBVIEW_chrome"]
[debug] [AndroidDriver] Available contexts: ["NATIVE_APP","WEBVIEW_chrome"]
[debug] [AndroidDriver] Getting a list of available webviews
[debug] [ADB] Getting connected devices...
[debug] [ADB] 1 device(s) connected
[debug] [ADB] Running 'C:\Users\Anjani\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s ZY223ZMPG6 shell cat /proc/net/unix'
[debug] [AndroidDriver] Found webviews: ["WEBVIEW_chrome"]
[debug] [AndroidDriver] Available contexts: ["NATIVE_APP","WEBVIEW_chrome"]
[debug] [AndroidDriver] Shutting down Android driver
[debug] [ADB] Getting connected devices...
[debug] [ADB] 1 device(s) connected
[debug] [ADB] Running 'C:\Users\Anjani\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s ZY223ZMPG6 shell am force-stop com.equationswork.enis'
[debug] [ADB] Pressing the HOME button
[debug] [ADB] Getting connected devices...
[debug] [ADB] 1 device(s) connected
[debug] [ADB] Running 'C:\Users\Anjani\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s ZY223ZMPG6 shell input keyevent 3'
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] Sending command to android: {"cmd":"shutdown"}
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] Received command result from bootstrap
[debug] [UiAutomator] Shutting down UiAutomator
[debug] [UiAutomator] Moving to state 'stopping'
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Got data from client: {"cmd":"shutdown"}
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Got command of type SHUTDOWN
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Returning result: {"status":0,"value":"OK, shutting down"}
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Closed client connection
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [UIAUTO STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: numtests=1
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [UIAUTO STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: stream=.
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [UIAUTO STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: id=UiAutomatorTestRunner
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [UIAUTO STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: test=testRunServer
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [UIAUTO STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: class=io.appium.android.bootstrap.Bootstrap
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [UIAUTO STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: current=1
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [UIAUTO STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS_CODE: 0
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [UIAUTO STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: stream=
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [UIAUTO STDOUT] Test results for WatcherResultPrinter=.
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [UIAUTO STDOUT] Time: 5.426
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [UIAUTO STDOUT] OK (1 test)
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [UIAUTO STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS_CODE: -1
[debug] [UiAutomator] UiAutomator shut down normally
[debug] [UiAutomator] Moving to state 'stopped'
[debug] [ADB] Attempting to kill all uiautomator processes
[debug] [ADB] Getting all processes with uiautomator
[debug] [ADB] Getting connected devices...
[debug] [ADB] 1 device(s) connected
[debug] [ADB] Running 'C:\Users\Anjani\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s ZY223ZMPG6 shell ps'
[ADB] No uiautomator process found to kill, continuing...
[debug] [UiAutomator] Moving to state 'stopped'
[debug] [Logcat] Stopping logcat capture
[debug] [ADB] Getting connected devices...
[debug] [ADB] 1 device(s) connected
[debug] [ADB] Running 'C:\Users\Anjani\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s ZY223ZMPG6 shell am force-stop io.appium.unlock'
[debug] [AndroidDriver] Not cleaning generated files. Add `clearSystemFiles` capability if wanted.
[debug] [BaseDriver] Event 'newSessionStarted' logged at 1528700164410 (12:26:04 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time))
[HTTP] <-- POST /wd/hub/session 400 21093 ms - 1026
[HTTP]
```

Comment: I am working on a similar issue here https://stackoverflow.com/q/50715334/8016330

At first glance it looks like this may have been an issue with appium java client.  Could you try updating to the most recent version and let me know if that helps

Comment: I am using Gradle, 
io.appium', name: 'java-client', version: '6.0.0'
org.seleniumhq.selenium', name: 'selenium-java', version: '3.12.0'
org.testng', name: 'testng', version:'6.14.3'
com.google.code.gson', name: 'gson', version: '2.8.5'

Comment: @AnjaniKumar,you got solution?

Comment: I also want to know if you ever got this resolved, as I'm having the same error reported in my framework.  Please respond.

Comment: I have already posted this answer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/54346053/6262727

Answer (score 2):

I hope you started appium server, may be with the same URL and port used to initialize driver object.
One more thing, please use one more for each loop to switch context by using string.contains("WEBVIEW")

Answer (score 2):

Go to developer option and enable below options --

1. USB debugging - Debug mode when USB is connected
2. Install via USB - Allow installing apps via USB
3. USB debugging (Security Settings) - Allow granting permissions and simulating input via USB debugging

This worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

run command : appium-doctor

analyse if there is Java_Home and Android_Home issue

go to bash profile and save it again

do : gradle build if there is any issue in device detection or device
   memory, see the logs take a new emulator in that case

run your project

This worked for me

Answer (score 1):

Appium logs tells problem is related to capabilities and
I Suppose in your path,after "\Anjani " there is a space,in desired capabilities.
This can be the reason.

```
("chromedriverExecutable","C:\\Users\\Anjani \\AppData\\....")
```

In my case i had set `"NO_Reset=false**e**" (with double "e" )`

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

If there is already an Appium server is running in the same IP and in the same port, this error message will be displayed. Make sure you terminate all the appium server before trying to start the appium server or you can specify new port for each appium server programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your device is connected, otherwise, it will throw that error you specified. To verify that you  have a connected device, run this command in terminal:

```
adb devices
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem may happen if we manually run Appium Desktop Server.
Try to run Appium server Thru Terminal "$ appium"
Run your script after Appium server is Up

Hope it will work...!

Answer (score 0):

In my case, It was due to DesiredCapabilities. Make sure "appPackage", "appActivity" or other Capabilities are correctly assigned.

Answer (score 0):

This error comes whenever we have issues in Desired capabilities. Look at desired capabilities and make sure all the data is correct. For me, I was passing Android version in int, wherein it wanted in String. Look at the entire error log, line by line u will get more insights. Also make sure appium UI is not open because bboth will be making use of same port.

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same issue, then I realised that my loopback ip address was not correct. Then I have changed the ip and it worked for me.
**from** http://127.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub **to** http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub
And the correct one is http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub.

Answer (score -1):

I faced this problem as well for Android automation project. 
Found solution. Deleting 'io.appium.uiautomator2.server' and 'io.appium.uiautomator2.server.test' packages before tests has helped.
These two packages will be reinstalled automatically during creating a session.

Answer (score -1):

Some times this problem occurs because **USB debugging is not accepting apps via USB install**.

For that go to developer option mode in your mobile and give all permissions to install app via USB.

Answer (score -2):

When you are passing the IP of the local host in URL method it has to be 127.0.0.1 like URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub") which is common for all the local hosts.

Hope it helps !!!!

Happy to help....

Answer (score -2):

I found the solution in this discussion forum> https://github.com/appium/appium/issues/11210

Maybe it can help you as well.

Changing the IP to 127.0.0.1 from 0.0.0.0 has worked for me. 
Also, try to restart the server before every execution. I have a written a small script for this in my test setup, maybe you can try the same.

If you are using a capability of AUTOMATION_NAME as ANDROID_UIAUTOMATOR2, you can face this issue.

```
desiredCap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.AUTOMATION_NAME,AutomationName.ANDROID_UIAUTOMATOR2);
```

Solution: 
1. Try either removing/commenting this line 
2. Or, run the commands below:

```
adb shell pm list packages -f > D://t.txt
adb uninstall io.appium.uiautomator2.server
adb uninstall io.appium.uiautomator2.server.test
```

These packages are auto-installed again when the session starts.