# It is impossible to create a new session because 'createSession' which takes HttpClient,

Tags: iphone, exception, webdriver, appium-ios

org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: It is impossible to create a new session because 'createSession' which takes HttpClient, InputStream and long was not found or it is not accessible
Build info: version: '3.12.0', revision: '7c6e0b3', time: '2018-05-08T14:04:26.12Z'

I am getting this error randomly i want to know the route cause for this issue in IOS

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple reason behind this issue. There are multiple ways to resolve this issues, depending upon, where these issues are coming from.

1)One issue which occur to me was DesireCapabilities.setCapability() key/value was not correct type. I have resolved this issue by just 
DesiredCapabilities.setCapability("capabilities_variable","capabilities_value");
setCapability("appWaitDuration", "600000"); here 600000 was String instead of long or int
Check your setCapability type whether it String/int/long.

2) Check **USB** Connection is Laptop or Computer, if not connected than same issue.

3) **ADB** Server might be problem. So *adb kill-server* and *adb start-server*

4) Try to change **USB** and try it out.

5) Sometimes, it might be a proxy issue(Laptop/Desktop may have some proxy setup 
in organization, since for Desktop/Laptops are connected with Mobile via TCP/IP Connection).

6) Sometimes, there might be permission required to access **PORT** (*sudo ufw allow portnumber* (UBUNTU SYSTEM))

7) Environment variable required **Android_SDK_Home** and Android Platform Tools path

Answer (score -1):

```
**> Solution 1st**

DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "xyz");
capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "6.0");
capabilities.setCapability("platformName", Platform.ANDROID);
capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", "com.hp.HPSupportAssistant");
capabilities.setCapability("appActivity", "com.hp.HPSupportAssistant.MainActivity");
 capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.NEW_COMMAND_TIMEOUT, 6000);    capabilities.setCapability(AndroidMobileCapabilityType.AUTO_GRANT_PERMISSIONS,true);
//desiredCap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.AUTOMATION_NAME, AutomationName.ANDROID_UIAUTOMATOR2);

**Here  comment below line and then run it will work** 
desiredCap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.AUTOMATION_NAME, AutomationName.ANDROID_UIAUTOMATOR2);

**solution 2nd Or keep above line in desired capabilities but before that do
run 3 cmd on cmd promt**
adb shell pm list packages -f > D://t.txt
adb uninstall io.appium.uiautomator2.server
adb uninstall io.appium.uiautomator2.server

desiredCap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.AUTOMATION_NAME, AutomationName.ANDROID_UIAUTOMATOR2);
```

Comment: I asked for IOS