# Getting Error While Running Appium code through Jenkins but its running fine on local

Tags: jenkins, appium, appium-android

While Executing the APPIUM code on the local system running fine but when Executing Through Jenkins Job It giving the Error.

It is impossible to create a new session because 'createSession' which takes HttpClient, InputStream and long was not found or it is not accessible

I've tried This Link [Error : impossible to create a new session because 'createSession' which takes HttpClient, InputStream and long was not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50792311/error-impossible-to-create-a-new-session-because-createsession-which-takes-h)

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you're suffering from a form of a [Jar Hell](https://dzone.com/articles/what-is-jar-hell), to wit there is a dependencies conflict due to using [Selenium Java Client](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java) libraries which are not compatible with the one which Appium has as the [transitive dependencies](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Transitive_Dependencies).

[image]

If you're managing dependencies manually - make sure that your project [classpath](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html) matches the above picture, however it's better to go for a dependency management solution like [Maven](http://maven.apache.org) or [Gradle](https://gradle.org) and make sure to have only Appium declared as an explicit dependency for your project - and the issue should go away.

Check out [Appium - Code Examples - Java](https://docs.experitest.com/display/TE/Java) for comprehensive information and a sample project you can use as a basis or reference.

Comment: Many Many Thanks !!